# Subsequent runs of rsync locally don't reduce data transferred

Tags: amazon-ec2, rsync, amazon-s3, s3fs

I have an EC2 instance with data I want to sync to a mounted, but remote, volume, as a backup.

`rsync` seems like the way to go with this, so as a test I took my test file (a Postgres pg_dump file) and used `rsync -v` to copy it to the mounted volume:

```
[ec2-user work]$ rsync -v dump.sql.1 ../backup/dump.sql
dump.sql.1

sent 821704315 bytes  received 31 bytes  3416650.09 bytes/sec
total size is 821603948  speedup is 1.00
```

Then, I ran it again, expecting to see minimal sent/received numbers because it would just be checksums.  Instead...

```
[ec2-user work]$ rsync -v dump.sql.1 ../backup/dump.sql
dump.sql.1

sent 821704315 bytes  received 31 bytes  3402502.47 bytes/sec
total size is 821603948  speedup is 1.00
```

I'm new to `rsync` so perhaps I'm missing something, but isn't the idea that the source and destination files are checked for differences, and then a patch is generated and applied to the destination?  Why is this not reducing the amount of data 'sent' to just the size of the checksums?

Some background if it's relevant:

the mounted volume is using [s3fs](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon), mounted with `s3fs <bucketname> backup`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rsync by default copies eveerything. You can use flags like -t or -c to make it check timestamps of files and don't re-transfer files who's last modification timestamp hasn't changed (-t), or where the checksum is still the same (-c). Another useful option is -a (I always use it), which sets -t and a few other options useful for archiving/backups.

Comment: Ha, sounds like I should've RTFM more carefully.  rsync -ac looks like it does the job for me, thanks!

Comment: Careful with -c -- it's expensive and really only needed if files can have the same timestamp, but differing contents.

Comment: Turns out I was wrong, with -c or without still doesnt' work.  But the problem, it turns out, is with s3fs, not resync usage.  See rsync related issues here: http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/issues/list?can=2&q=rsync&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Priority+Milestone+Owner+Summary&cells=tiles